# Can QGIS manage non-spatial PostgreSQL database?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, query, update

I have a database with a table with plots. This table has a spatial field for the area. Also, I have another table with the owners. An owner can own some plots, and there is an `"id_owner"` field in the plot table.

My question is if it is possible to use the table `"owner"` in QGIS? If I can show the data, or make queries or update fields in `"owner"` table.

I have searched before but I have not seen exactly this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,

- You can open and edit non geometry table from PostGIS in QGIS.
- You can open PostGIS views in QGIS. Also spatial views.
- You can edit PostGIS views in QGIS, if you write an 'instead of trigger' in PostgreSQL.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To show non-spatial tables in QGIS 3.8:

1. Right click on the database connection and click "Edit Connection"
   [image]
2. Check the box to "Also list tables with no geometry"
   [image]